# Arccos telescopic sum: $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \arccos \frac{2k^2}{4k^4+1}$

Tags: trigonometry

Compute the finite sum:
$\arccos \frac{2 \cdot 1^2}{4\cdot 1^4+1}+...+\arccos \frac{2 \cdot n^2}{4\cdot n^4+1}$

Please help. I have no idea what to do. There should be a telescopation but I can’t find it.

Comment: Any sum is not do-able by hand, so let us know if this one is from a book/exam. If so, then one would try. It appears to be not do-able by hand.

Comment: Mathematica tells me this series doesn't converge...

Comment: I can come up with a formula if there were a square root in the denominator, i.e., $\arccos\tfrac{2n^2}{\sqrt{4n^4+1}}$. Do you think this might be the case?

Comment: The problem is from a Romanian Mathematics Magazine, so there are chances it is wrong. But we’ll have to wait at least one month until the next volume is published to see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, just a try. By partial fraction decomposition, you get
$$z_k:= \frac{2k^2}{4k^4+1} = \frac{k}{2(2k^2-2k+1)} - \frac{k}{2(2k^2+2k+1)} $$
Then you could use the fact that 
$$\arccos(z) = \frac \pi 2 - \arcsin(z) $$
and the identity
$$\arcsin\left(x\sqrt{1-y^2}-y\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)=\arcsin(x) - \arcsin(y), $$
which would lead to the system
$$\begin{split}
\frac{k}{2(2k^2-2k+1)} = x_k\sqrt{1-y_k^2} + c_k, \\
\frac{k}{2(2k^2+2k+1)} = y_k\sqrt{1-x_k^2} + c_k,
\end{split}$$
However, the solution $(x_k,y_k)$ even for $c_k =0$ is horrendous and does not lead to a telescoping sum, by which I mean
$$\arcsin(y_{k-1}) = \arcsin(x_k). $$

I doubt that you could find a $c_k$ such that the sum telescopes. *If* you managed to find such a $c_k$, then
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \arccos(z_k) = \frac{\pi n }{2} - \sum_{k=1}^n \arcsin(z_k) = \frac{\pi n}{2} - \left[\arcsin\left(\frac 2 5\right) + \arcsin\left(\frac{2n^2}{4n^4+1} \right) \right]. $$

---

**EDIT.** (Here I follow @bjorn93's suggestion in the comments, for which I am thankful.) If, on the other hand, you had 
$$z_k = \frac{2k^2}{\sqrt{4k^2+1}}, $$
then, by using the identity
$$\tan(\arccos(z)) = \frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}}{z} $$
you get
$$\begin{split}
\arccos(z_k) &= \arctan( \tan \arccos(z_k)) = \arctan\Bigg(\frac{\sqrt{1-z_k^2}}{z_k} \Bigg)\\ &= \arctan \left( \frac{\sqrt{4k^4 +1}}{2k^2} \sqrt{1-\frac{4k^4}{4k^4+1}}\right)  \\
&= \arctan\left( \frac{1}{2k^2} \right)
\end{split}$$
You can check that, by the arctangent identity
$$\arctan(x) - \arctan(y) = \arctan \left( \frac{x-y}{1+xy} \right),$$
we can split, for $k \geq 1$,
$$\arctan\left( \frac 1 {2k^2}\right) = \arctan\left( \frac{k}{k+1}\right) - \arctan\left( \frac{k-1}k\right). $$
(To find this decomposition, you may solve the recurrence relation $1+x_kx_{k-1} = 2k^2 (x_k - x_{k-1})$ with the initial condition $x_0 = 0$.) Hence the sum telescopes:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \arccos\left( \frac{2k^2}{\sqrt{4k^4+1}} \right) = \sum_{k=1}^n \arctan\left( \frac{1}{2k^2} \right) = \arctan\left( \frac{n}{n+1} \right). $$